# Maven: WARNING Unable to autodetect 'javac' path, using 'javac' from the environment

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, javac

When running Maven, I get this output:

```
[WARNING] Unable to autodetect 'javac' path, using 'javac' from the environment.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will see this error message when Maven is being run using a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) which is a stripped down version of Java that can only *execute* Java code but can't *compile* sources.

To fix the warning, install the **JDK** (Java *Development* Kit) and set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to the newly installed version of Java.

You can put this into the file `.mavenrc` if you want; then only Maven will use this version of Java.

Comment: What if this happens in IntelliJ?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz In the configuration for the Maven runner is an option to select the JRE to use. Make sure it points to a SDK. See the "JRE" field here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#build_through_maven

Comment: @AaronDigulla thanks for this, I put in the environment variables box:  JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1  and it worked fine

Comment: Why this warning at all? I have JDK set up but did not bother to configure JAVA_HOME because I want to switch quickly between Java versions using OS-provided tooling, e.g. `archlinux-java`. All is fine for me, aside from the Maven warning.

Comment: @mikhailian: In most cases, this means that a "random" version of Java is being used (i.e. whatever is on the path). This leads to nonrepeatable builds for many people without them being aware of this. It's also not always possible to provide a clean path or to put Java on the path at all. JAVA_HOME will always work and solve all these problems.

Comment: Check `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner -> JRE` if you are using IntelliJ. If not, check project structure.

Comment: @ChrisWu This should be an answer; nobody will find this comment :-)

Comment: Isn't this just a warning we could ignore? On a Debian 11 with `openjdk-17-jdk-headless` installed I'm getting this warnings while building [DSpace](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC7x/Installing+DSpace) but the build ends succesfully. `javac` run fine, with or without JAVA_HOME set (with `sudo update-java-alternatives -l`)

Answer (score 8):

If you're running Maven from Eclipse (e.g. Run As : Maven Install), make sure your environment is configured with correct JRE (you'll need JDK, not JRE). Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE. Select JDK if it's there or add JDK if it's not.

Answer (score 7):

A friend of mine experienced this issue when working on building a **Java** project in **Ubuntu 18.04**.

When he runs the command:

```
maven clean build
```

He gets the warning:

```
[WARNING] Unable to autodetect 'javac' path, using 'javac' from the environment
```

And then gets this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project geostore-model: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
```

**Here's how it was solved**:

The issue was that he did not have `javac` (Java programming language compiler) installed on his machine. To confirm, we ran the command:

```
javac --version
```

And we got no version output

So we installed the **Java development kit** that contains `javac` and all of its dependencies using the command:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Afterwhich we ran the command `javac --version` and got the output:

```
javac 11.0.9.1
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

try to set `JAVA_HOME`  in the MyComputer-->Environment Variable

Answer (score 1):

`sudo yum install java-sdk`
Centos finds the correct SDK with the -devel sufix

Answer (score 1):

`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`  for java version 8
`sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel` for java version 11

Comment: Note: This will just install Java. You may still have to point Maven to use the correct one using one of the other answers, for example when you have both 8 and 11 installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `IntelliJ`:
Check `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner -> JRE`.
Also check `File | Project Structure`.
Most of the time you will find a wrong java version.

Answer (score 1):

For people who don't find that the accepted answer applies: check if your `maven-compiler-plugin` has the `fork` option set to `true` in `pom.xml`, like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This seems to be a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-278903) in IntelliJ that hasn't been fixed as of 21.10.2022.

Answer (score 0):

`Right click on project -> Properties -> Java Compiler` then `uncheck` **Use compliance from execution environment...** and then select a compiler in **Compiler Compliance level**

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac:

```
java_version=1.8
#version=1.8.0_91
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $java_version)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac deleting the .idea folder in intelliJ worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ 2022.3.2 and had to remove the "\bin" part from my JAVA_HOME path to fix the "problem".

Answer (score 0):

analised:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>/usr/local/pje/jdk-11.0.10+9/bin/javac</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was still getting this error, even though I had updated my path etc. and `javac -version` was giving the right version of Java.

I fixed it by just restarting my computer :), so that is worth trying as well if the problem persists.