# JAVA path in Linux environment variable warning

Tags: java, linux, path, environment-variables, java-17

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTiTU.png)I just installed Kali and am Java 17 (JDK & JRE) and am trying to configure JAVA_HOME as an environment variable.

But Im getting [WARNING] Unable to autodetect 'javac' path, using 'javac' from the environment.

To solve my error as mentioned

Comment: What do you get when you run `javac -version`?   I suspect that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861520 will answer your question ... and that (in fact) you didn't install a full JDK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven: WARNING Unable to autodetect 'javac' path, using 'javac' from the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861520/maven-warning-unable-to-autodetect-javac-path-using-javac-from-the-environ)

Comment: Make sure it's the JDK you use in JAVA_HOME and **pre** pend `$JAVA_HOME/bin:` to PATH

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.